# Regex capture group is empty, unless I use the [QSA] flag

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I'm making a rewrite rule that will rewrite `art/slug/...` to `art/.../?art=slug`. The rule I wrote works, but only produce the intended query string when using `[QSA]`.

Right above the rule is `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, to prevent looping once the rewritten url matches an existing file.

I have tested the following rules, and navigated to `art/test/` where `$_GET` is being `var_dump`'d. Here are the results :

`RewriteRule ^art/([^/]*)/?(.*) art/$2?art=$1     [L]` outputs `'art' => string ''`
`RewriteRule ^art/([^/]*)/?(.*) art/$2?art=$1 [QSA,L]` outputs `'art' => string 'test'`
`RewriteRule ^art/([^/]*)/?(.*) art/$2?art=test   [L]` outputs `'art' => string 'test'`

From my understanding, `QSA` is meant to append the "original" query string to the "rewritten" one.
In my situation I don't have nor want any query string in the original url; it's entirely made during the rewritting, so in the first example I don't understand why my `art` key is set to empty, (though it is not undefined).

Let's assume that I misunderstood `QSA`, and that it is required in order to produce any query string at all; then how comes that in the third example, hardcoding the value of query string works without the `QSA` flag ?
Does removing `QSA` somehow change the way my regex works ?

---

I'm running a local server with WAMP 3.0.6 64bit, Apache 2.4.23, and PHP 7.0.10

Comment: I don't get it. Care to elaborate ? 
It's not the capture group after /? that ends up being empty, it's the capture group before that. And how does QSA come into play ?

Comment: give more info about all URLs that you tested with rules above

Comment: I did write two pair of parenthesis didn't I ? And using example 3, the $2 is definitely not empty: navigating to `art/test/edit.php` does land me on `art/edit.php?art=test`.

Comment: Sorry i was mixed

Comment: I did find something fishy testing out some more urls. I'll edit my post with more examples.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your issue , you should prevent looping that happened in all cases you mentioned above , so before rewriting you should make sure there is no `query  string` , otherwise looping will happen at all of them and that why you missed `test` in first line .

Add this before any rule and test again :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.+)$
```

Comment: Looping will be the death of me. I had assumed I was preventing it with my own RewriteCond, but it looks like I was wrong.